# Has anyone used rpy2 with py2exe?

Tags: c#, python, com, py2exe, rpy2

I am hoping to port some Python code that uses RPY2 to run R functions into dlls using py2exe then, ultimately, to COM objects for integration with a C# project of a collaborator.

If incorporating rpy2 into py2exe is not too painful, this could save a fair bit of recoding. Does anyone have suggestions based on their experience?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given the current state of extremely limited support of rpy2 on Microsoft Windows, I'd consider other options.

Comment: Thanks @lgautier. I usually use rpy2 on OSX, but am trying to distribute some development code with collaborators who are completely Windows people. I may still try it, but appreciate the thought that I may need to look elsewhere.

Comment: You'll have to find what is for you the best option between changing the way you interface with R, changing the OS of the collaborators, implement a client-server solution with rpy2, help the rpy2 project to offer support for Windows.

Comment: I have been searching online for a while, but I can't find anything related until I see this post. Does anyone have any luck packaging rpy2 with pyinstaller on Mac? Is it even possible? Thanks!